# Swift 3 add new contact with phone and email information

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, contacts

I'm trying to prompt the user to create a new contact and pass in information. (specifically a phone and email)

I've found numerous examples of using a CNMutableContact and adding an email to it. However, any of the code involving the CNContact gives me a "Use of undeclared type" error.

How can I setup my class to prompt the user to save the contact?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
import ContactsUI

//add CNContactViewControllerDelegate to your ViewController
class ViewController: UIViewController , CNContactViewControllerDelegate {

func addPhoneNumber(phNo : String) {
  if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
      let store = CNContactStore()
      let contact = CNMutableContact()
      let homePhone = CNLabeledValue(label: CNLabelHome, value: CNPhoneNumber(stringValue :phNo ))
      contact.phoneNumbers = [homePhone]
      let controller = CNContactViewController(forUnknownContact : contact)
      controller.contactStore = store
      controller.delegate = self
      self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
      self.navigationController!.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
  }
}
```

Comment: @BijenderSinghShekhawat you also need to import Contacts and ContactsUI

Comment: @ganesh but how do you add it to the user's phone database(I'm guess it's CoreData)

Answer (score 3):

You Can Do Something Like This.

```
extension ViewController: CNContactViewControllerDelegate {

    func showNewContactViewController() {

        let contactViewController: CNContactViewController = CNContactViewController(forNewContact: nil)
        contactViewController.contactStore = CNContactStore()
        contactViewController.delegate = self
        let navigationController: UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: contactViewController)
        present(navigationController, animated: false) {
            print("Present")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4**

```
import ContactsUI
```

implement delegate `CNContactViewControllerDelegate`

```
@IBAction func UserTap_Handler(_ sender: Any) {

        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
        let con = CNContact()
        let vc = CNContactViewController(forNewContact: con)
        vc.delegate = self
        _ = self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }

    //MARK:- contacts delegates
    func contactViewController(_ viewController: CNContactViewController, didCompleteWith contact: CNContact?) {
        print("dismiss contact")
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
    func contactViewController(_ viewController: CNContactViewController, shouldPerformDefaultActionFor property: CNContactProperty) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
```