# Can I add my app's custom link in iOS native contacts?

Tags: ios, contacts

In android some apps like paytm and truecaller shows their custom links in android contact list, can we achieve same in iOS ?

for example see the screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did achieve my requirement with help of @Alex Chase's answer, here is my code.

I added the contact or I can also edit the contact to add the url to my app.

```
/* Add demo contact */
CNContactStore *store = [[CNContactStore alloc] init];
CNMutableContact *contact = [CNMutableContact new];
NSString *url = [@"data_to_be_passed" stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet]];
CNLabeledValue *value1 = [[CNLabeledValue alloc] initWithLabel:CNLabelHome value:[CNPhoneNumber phoneNumberWithStringValue:@"9999999999"]];
CNLabeledValue *value2 = [[CNLabeledValue alloc] initWithLabel:@"CRMNEXT" value:[@"openMyApp://" stringByAppendingString:url]];

contact.phoneNumbers = @[value1];
contact.urlAddresses = @[value2];
contact.givenName = @"Harry Potter";

CNSaveRequest *request = [[CNSaveRequest alloc] init];
[request addContact:contact toContainerWithIdentifier:nil];

[store executeSaveRequest:request error:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

This is partially a duplicate of
[Swift 3 add new contact with phone and email information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41755969/swift-3-add-new-contact-with-phone-and-email-information)

Create a new contact and populate the `urlAddresses` property with an array of the URL strings you want to associate with the new contact.

```
import Contacts
import ContactsUI

...

func addPhoneNumber(phNo : String) {
  if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
      let store = CNContactStore()
      let contact = CNMutableContact()
      let homePhone = CNLabeledValue(label: CNLabelHome, value: CNPhoneNumber(stringValue :phNo ))
      contact.phoneNumbers = [homePhone]
      contact.urlAddresses = ["myURL1", "myURL2"]
      let controller = CNContactViewController(forUnknownContact : contact)
      controller.contactStore = store
      controller.delegate = self
      self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
      self.navigationController!.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
  }
}
```

Comment: That can be a possible way, using url scheme I can open my app. Thanks !!